# What's the name of this plant?

Tags: identification

What's this? Found in Eastern Europe/ Poland

[image]

Comment: I love testing my knee jerk or immediate thoughts when first seeing a picture of a plant.  So this is more for me.  Also generates more answers and feedback, grins.  Amaranth sp.

Comment: Can you take another photograph please - this one's slightly blurry and its not possible to see the flower buds clearly, nor is it possible to magnify it, resolution's not high enough

Comment: Does it have a squared stem?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a foxglove? Digitalis lutea? or Dark Mullein Verbascum nigrum? both are right for the area of Europe but the photo is so fuzzy very difficult to identify?
the general shape of the plant is right for the first one, the flower shape is right for the second however they're both wrong in my opinion... i'm thinking perhaps a type of comfrey Symphytum tuberosum/officinale, the first one is yellow flowering and about 30cm high the second one is 60cm+ and pink/purple and white flowering but both areas of distribution in Europe are not eastern- might have to think about this one...
the comfrey one would have rough leaves and might irritate the skin while the other two would be quite smooth to the touch...

Comment: I've been looking and I came across Mullein as well.  I think that you are correct!  You should post pictures from the internet that are posted in line.  They've changed the search engine a bit have you noticed?  You have to click 'images' to get the file they used to post right in the first list off the search engine.  Pictures are now larger and come with information as to what plant you are looking at.  No ads mixed in.   Happened in this last week?

Answer (score 0):

Amaranth, for example the cultivar [Sunset Goldilocks](https://www.adaptiveseeds.com/product/highlighted-varieties/adaptive-seeds-originals/amaranth-sunset-goldilocks-organic) pictured below:

[image: Amaranth]